# How to fix UDP communication problem between Android application written in Flutter and server written in Python

Tags: python, flutter, dart, udp

I'm facing challenges establishing a connection between an Android application written in Dart and a Python server. The Android application is running on an Android emulator.

I successfully established a connection using WebSocket, but I'm encountering difficulties with UDP. Surprisingly, there are no error messages.

Here is the part of Dart code for application:

```
    final serverAddress = InternetAddress('10.0.2.15');
    const port = 50001;
    _clientSocket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, port);
    _clientSocket.send('Hello from Flutter'.codeUnits, serverAddress, port);

    _clientSocket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
      if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
        Datagram dg = _clientSocket.receive()!;
        String message = String.fromCharCodes(dg.data);
        print('Received message: $message');
      }
    });
```

Here is the server code:

```
import socket

localIP = "127.0.0.1"
print(localIP)

localPort = 50001
bufferSize = 1024

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind((localIP, localPort))
print("UDP server up and listening")

while True:
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]

    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)

    print(f"{clientMsg}\n{clientIP}\n-----------------\n")

    # Sending a reply to the client
    replyMsg = f"Hello test agent, thanks for messaging!\n-----------------\n"
    UDPServerSocket.sendto(str.encode(replyMsg), address)
```

Comment: Are you running client and server on separate machines?  If so use `''` for `localIP` on the server to listen on all interfaces instead of binding only to the localhost interface.  FYI you also don't typically use `bind` on the client.

Comment: Both application and server are running on the same machine. 
How should i connect to that UDP socket if now by binding on the client? Should i use any other dart library?

Comment: UDP is connectionless. Your send has the address and port. I’m not familiar with Dart though. If the client was Python you’d just use `sendto()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing you have to do is change in python:

```
import socket

localIP = "127.0.0.1"
```

to

```
import socket

localIP = "0.0.0.0"
```

If you run on different machines, that already works for you.

now if you run client and server on the same machine then you have to specify a different source port in dart

```
  final serverAddress = InternetAddress('10.0.2.15');
    const srcPort = 5011;
    const destPort = 50001;
    var clientSocket =
        await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, srcPort);
    clientSocket.send('Hello from Flutter'.codeUnits, serverAddress, destPort);

    clientSocket.listen((RawSocketEvent event) {
      if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
        Datagram dg = clientSocket.receive()!;
        String message = String.fromCharCodes(dg.data);
        print('Received message: $message');
      }
    });
```